# How to convert Attributes to String?

Tags: java, hashmap, ldap, openldap

I want to convert `Attribute`s to `String` so that I can trim and get a substring of the attribute value.

Here is my code:

```
Attribute attrs = match.getAttributes();

NamingEnumeration e = attrs.getAll();
System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
System.out.print(attrs.get("uniqueMember"));

unique_members[i] = attrs.get("uniqueMember");
```

I am facing an error in the last line where I want to store the value of `uniqueMember` to the `unique_members` array. Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Attribute to String

I have tried the following so far:

```
unique_members[i] = (String)attrs.get("uniqueMember");
```

It doesn't solve the issue and I am getting error:

> Cannot cast attribute to String.

Comment: what kind of data is stored inside `uniquemember`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unique_members[i] = attrs.get("uniqueMember").toString()` to convert the attribute value to a string.

For more informationens see the javadoc of [BasicAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/BasicAttribute.html) or [javax.naming.directory.Attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attribute.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Javadoc of [Attributes class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.html). You can use [getValue(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the value of a specific attribute.

Comment: By using `getValue(String)` you do not need to cast or convert to `String` because the return type is already `String`.

Comment: You refering to a wron class because of a type in OP's question. attr is an istance of  `javax.naming.directory.Attribute` not of `java.util.jar.Attributes`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use null-safe [`Objects.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) for getting string representation--it won't throw exception if `attrs.get()` returns null, which may happen if attribute is not found:

```
unique_members[i] = Objects.toString(attrs.get("uniqueMember"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here searching for how to convert any Object with its attributes to a string, you can consider using [`ReflectionToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html):

```
ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(anyObject);
```